# Modifying .htaccess file to accommodate 301 redirect and page caching

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

With an effort to improve SEO ratings, I am adding some elements to `.htaccess` file that will accommodate both `301` redirect and page caching.

My code in .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<Filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|min.css|swf|ico|woff|mp3)$">
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</Filesmatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3} [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.co$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.co/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I am able to see the `301` redirect, but there is no update on the caching. I tried using the following command to see the changes

```
curl -I www.websitename.com
```

and found the following results

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sun, 13 Mar 2016 05:12:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://www.website.co/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Could you please help to check why cache control is not enabled from the server side?

Comment: Might have more luck over at Server fault

Comment: Are you sure expired is enabled? `sudo a2enmod expires`

Comment: module expires is active already

Answer (score 2):

Your `ExpiresDefault` directive is defined under the following group:

```
<Filesmatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|min.css|swf|ico|woff|mp3)$">
```

As you can understand, only the requests ending with one of the above listed pages/items will get the `ExpiresDefault` header from server.

In your curl request, you are merely requesting the homepage, which does not request a file ending with those extensions. Therefore this behaviour. You can try to modify your rules as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
    <Filesmatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|js|css|swf|ico|woff|mp3)$">
        ExpiresDefault "modified plus 1 month"
    </Filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```